# How to avoid boot delay caused by signed libraries?

Tags: windows, dll, windows-7, certificate, code-signing

I have a startup service that uses some DLLs signed by myself.
In certain conditions (when the computer is connected to a network but it can't reach the internet) (Windows for) each signed library tries to validate its certificate somehow, increasing the boot time by a few seconds.

How to prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google "disable crl checking" and take the first hit.  This isn't a real solution of course.  A real one takes different measures, ones that you cannot take care of yourself.  Somebody has to fix the Internet connection problem.  If your customer cannot take care of this, I'd recommend you suggest them to accept an unsigned version of your binaries.  Ask more questions about this at superuser.com